# Where can i can find the configuration file for VLP16 calibration for ROS?

Tags: ros, calibration, vlp16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to calibrate my velodyne on ROS indigo VLP16 and I don't find the xml file to generate the yaml file.

Like the 32db.xml to generate 32bd.yaml.

Where can i find it ?

Ty

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235583/where-can-i-can-find-the-configuration-file-for-vlp16-calibration-for-ros?/) by [ArthurAlear](https://answers.ros.org/users/27019/arthuralear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/222390/

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ArthurAlear](https://answers.ros.org/users/27019/arthuralear/) on 2016-06-20**:
Thanks for your answer !